# Need help to debug an issue with query-replace command

Tags: debugging, query-replace

The query-replace command used to work perfectly for me. Recently, it fails with a symptom like this:

[updated]
Assuming the code looks like: (for example)

set_flaag(var1);

set_flaag(var2);

Now I issued the command "M-x query-replace[RET]flaag[RET]flag[RET]"
It highlights all the "flaag" in the screen, note the cursor will be on '(' of first line after high-lighting the first "flaag" in line 1. Then as soon as I typed a 'y' to proceed, it puts the 'y' in the buffer and quit without replacing "flaag" to "flag". (So line 1 looks like "set_flaagy(var1)".)

If I change the command to:
"M-x query-replace[RET]flaa[RET]fla[RET]". This way the cursor will be on the letter 'g' instead of '(' after highlight the matching parts in line 1. And the command works correctly.

I guess may be some of my new settings in init.el may have screwed up something. But I have no clue how to resolve/debug this issue. Would appreciate a help.

Comment: If you do not see the same problem when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. You can do that using command `comment-region` (`C-u` uncomments): Comment out 1/2 your init file, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, etc., to narrow it down to the problematic code. This is quick to do because it is a binary search.

Comment: Drew, thanks very much showing me this debug technique. WIll try it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following Drew's suggested debug approach, I was able to identify the package/code that caused this issue. It is caused by an out-of-date flash-paren.el. I loaded the most up-to-date version and the issue was fixed.

Thanks very much.